# Android Studio - Global search not working properly after Arctic Fox update

Tags: android-studio, search

After I updated to the Arctic fox update the global search function started behaving weirdly. (I am referring to the double shift search)

1. The sorting of the results is very annoying. In the `All` tab it shows class variables and xml files first instead of classes. Previously it showed classes first and then everything else.
2. It does not find results for things I misspell while previously it did an excellent job at that.

Is there any way to fix this behavior?

(I know I can click on the `Classes` tab to only see classes but that is one extra step that I don't want to do EVERY time I search for something which is about 300 times per day)

Answer (score 0):

Click on the Filtering icon at the top right corner of the global search dialog. It seems it remembers the filters.

[image]

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).